# How do I format code on a phone?

Tags: discussion, support, code-formatting, mobile-web

I figured out that it is convenient to post or answer simple questions on Stack Overflow by using my phone. But I don't know how to format my code. How can I do it?

Comment: 1. This question belongs to meta. 2. You format it using ticks, but yes - you're more limited.

Comment: I retain to do so, that's just cumbersome.

Comment: When you say *"through phone"* do you mean a mobile browser, or app?

Answer (score 2):

It's actually not that hard.

You simply have to

1. Type out your code
2. Select the code
3. Tap on the "Code Sample" button

and your code will be formatted!

[image]

Comment: Java on an iPhone, surely you jest.